# Adding image in matplotlib plot creates blank output showing only axis

Tags: image, matplotlib

I have been trying to add an image to my matplotlib plot. The image is a legend of my plot. My original graph has too many plots within so, I tried to generalise the legend to make it easy for the eye.

Though I could export the image to matplotlib, I notice that the attached script plots data along with the legend(image) in one window and also opens another blank plot showing only the axis.

What am I doing wrong? 
Feel free to add any image of your choice for testing.

`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv
import matplotlib.image as image

axes = plt.gca()

im = image.imread('plot/minPlot/legend.png')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(im,aspect='auto', extent=(3,5,2,3), zorder=-1)

plt.xlabel('X Axis')
plt.ylabel('Y Axis')
plt.title('')

x1, y1 = [-1,12],[1,4]
x2, y2 = [1,10],[3,2]
plt.plot(x1,y1,x2,y2,marker='o')

plt.show()
```

`

Comment: Remove `axes = plt.gca()`

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidG posted, the 
'axes = plt.gca()' was causing an additional empty plot. I used the plt.gca() for setting the limits of the x,y axis. After going through https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html, I can directly call the xlim and ylim functions from the plt class. So, I can get rid of plt.gca() call.